# Running time in big-o notation of Boruvka Parallel algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, runtime, big-o, minimum-spanning-tree

Imagine we are only parallelising the step in which we search for the smallest weighted edge for each component.
The original run time of Boruvka is O(E log V). How it will change after parallelised?

Comment: It will still be O(E log V), because the computer it's running on has a fixed constant number of electronic components and still cannot do more than O(1) work in O(1) time, even in parallel.

Comment: If the complexity is the same, how can parallelization speed up the algorithm?

Comment: Because 2E log V is a hundred times faster than 200E log V, despite the fact that they have the same asymptotic growth rate O(E log V). When two running times have the same asymptotic growth rate, that doesn't mean they are equal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithms_for_minimum_spanning_trees#Borůvka%27s_algorithm. Here in the paragraph of boruvka algorithm, the running time for finding the lightest edge is O(m/p + log n + log p), so shouldn't the running time then be O(E/p log v)?